# Add multiple dynamic classes to LinkButton in a ListView

Tags: asp.net, css, listview

I am trying to add multiple classes to a LinkButton in a ListView.

This works:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAttendee" runat="server" CssClass='CheckedInTrue attendee'>
```

And this works:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAttendee" runat="server" CssClass='<%#Eval("CheckedIn") %>'>
```

But this **does not**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAttendee" runat="server" CssClass='CheckedIn<%#Eval("CheckedIn") %> attendee'>
```

When I do it the 3rd way, the class is rendered literally, like this:

```
<a id="lvAttendees_ctrl1_lbAttendee" class="CheckedIn<%#Eval("CheckedIn") %> attendee" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lvAttendees$ctrl1$lbAttendee','')">
            <span style="display:none;">2</span>
                <p class="studentName">Joseph Conrad</p>
                <p class="studentID">13526861</p>
            </a>
```

Comment: The answer was this:
`<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAttendee" runat="server" CssClass='<%# "attendee CheckedIn" + Eval("CheckedIn") %>'>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's work for me

```
<a id="lvAttendees_ctrl1_lbAttendee" class='<%# String.Format("CheckedIn {0} attendee", Eval("CheckedIn")) %>' href="javascript:__doPostBack('lvAttendees$ctrl1$lbAttendee','')">
                <span style="display:none;">2</span>
                    <p class="studentName">Joseph Conrad</p>
                    <p class="studentID">13526861</p>
                </a>
```